# Why does this PHP code give a Parse Error

Tags: php

for my mini forum I have a "topics" table with fields id(int), title(txt) and post(txt) and I am trying to get the user to see different pages depending on the topics they click on via  topicPage.php:

```
  <?
//send a query to retrieve all titles from the topics database
$query = "SELECT * FROM topics" ;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("something went wrong with this query");

    ?>

<span class="subtext">  <?
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<a href = 'topicPage.php?tid=$row['id']'>" .$row['title']. " </a>"." <br>" ." <br>";

}
?>
```

I get a parse error on the line with the echo function.

Here's the exact error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /index.php on line 85

Comment: http://php.net/string#language.types.string.parsing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following part :

```
echo "<a href = 'topicPage.php?tid=$row['id']'>";
```

is *too complex*.

You must help PHP find out what is the variable, using the [**Complex (curly) syntax**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) :

```
echo "<a href = 'topicPage.php?tid={$row['id']}'>";
```

Comment: It's not too complex, it's just the wrong syntax. Writing `echo "<a href = 'topicPage.php?tid=$row[id]'>";` would work ;)

Comment: but why does $row['title'] work fine?

Comment: @nikic yes, it would work ;; @algorithmicCoder because that one is not inside a string.

Comment: using the {} fixes things but why is using a $row['id'] "too complex"...or rather when is something too complex?...when it is not a raw variable/ when its an expression?

Comment: I will not be able to define when `{}` are necessary and when then are not without risking doing a couple of mistakes *(I generally use them just to make my code more readable)* -- but there are a couple of example in the manual, that might help you a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Using single quotes these kind of issues seldom appear:

```
echo '<a href="topicPage.php?tid='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['title'].'</a><br /><br />';
```

Also, you don't need to concatenate the `<br />` tags like that, you can supply them in one big hunk of string.

Answer (score 0):

Treat `$row['id']` the same way as `$row['title']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href = 'topicPage.php?tid=" . $row['id'] . "'>" .$row['title']. " </a>"." <br>" ." <br>";
```

try to keep same style ...